# checkbox.isChecked return "null" : Why ?! - Android

Tags: android, checkbox, ischecked

I have put a checkbox in a activity.

This is the XML :

> ```
> <CheckBox
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:text="@string/preference_storingIDs"
>             android:id="@+id/preferencecheckBoxSaveID"
>             android:layout_below="@+id/preferenceImageButtonURL"
>             android:layout_alignRight="@+id/preferenceImageButtonURL"
>             android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/preferenceImageButtonURL"
>             android:checked="true" />
> ```

In the code :

Initializing :

> public CheckBox chkBoxSaveID;

And set the checkbox:

> chkBoxSaveID = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.preferencecheckBoxSaveID);

In other activity, same things:

```
 CheckBox chkBoxSaveID;
 chkBoxSaveID = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.preferencecheckBoxSaveID);
```

Then, i have create a if condition.

```
if(chkBoxSaveID.isChecked()){
do blabla
}
else {
do blabla }
```

but, when i running the emulator, i have this error:

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual methode 'boolean android.widget.Checkbox.isChecked()' on a null object reference

I don't understand why. I've try to fix the value at "True" but it's same.
Can you explain me please ?

Regards,

Comment: **WILD GUESS**: You didn't set the **ContentView** to the same layout which contains that CheckBox. Therefore, it can't find that CheckBox, and returns **null**.

Comment: Hi Der Gol...lum, thanks for your help.
If I understand, before i use the checkbox, i need to modify the ContentView like that :

> setContentView(R.layout.activity_preferences_accueil); 

The checkbox is on the layout preferences, and i need to check the state of the checkbox in the login layout.

Comment: Yes. If you don't have the View in the current layout, that View won't be found by `findViewById()`.

Comment: so I can write something like this ?

      setContentView(R.layout.activity_preferences_accueil);
      chkBoxSaveID = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.preferencecheckBoxSaveID);
// Test with my checkbox
setContentView(R.layout.Activiy_login);

Comment: Yes, but... WHY? you can check a preference WITHOUT the PreferenceScreen.

Comment: I've understand that when you have said " If you don't have the View in the current layout, that View won't be found by findViewById()"
Sorry i'm a newbee in Android.. Can you explain differently ? Please

Comment: If you are only going to retrieve a preference value, you can do that **directly**. You **don't need** to set the layout to that of the PreferenceScreen, to retrieve a preference value. **No Views** involved. Just **get the values** from the preference file. As explained here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#ReadingPrefs

Comment: From the preference file ? How ?

Comment: I updated my comment. Follow that link.

Comment: Thank you, I will check that.

Answer (score 0):

The error says that your CheckBox view is null.

Make sure that the following line returns a valid CheckBox object and not null:

chkBoxSaveID = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.preferencecheckBoxSaveID);

Comment: Hi MarkySmarky.
The following line returns a not null object. Did you know where is my error?